# Enable logging to two different locations in log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm brand new to log4net, and I'm trying to maintain some legacy code that uses it.  I've noticed that having two static classes that tell log4net to log to different locations are tripping over each other.

The classes each have a static constructor that looks like this

```cs
static Logger() {
    _Logger = new X.LoggingService.AppLogger(
                X.UtilityServer.Configuration.ConfigInfo.LoggerConfigFile);
}
```

except with different config values; both of these static classes are initializing the same `AppLogger` helper class.  The second class to initialize is overwriting the initialization of the first.  I think I've tracked the problem down to here:

```cs
private  ILog Log  {
    get {
        if (!_ConfiguratorSet) {
            _ConfiguratorSet = true;
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(_ConfigFile)); //<--- STATIC
        }
        return _log; 
    }
}
```

**Since I absolutely do not have to support thread safety**, should I just get remove the if statement?  Would calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure` every time I need to log something be prohibitively expensive?  Is there a better way?  This code was written using log4net version 1.2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, what shall be happening is:

1. Configure log4net (do this **once** at app start up - this is very slow)
2. Use dependency injection to pass ILog to the classes (better) *or* service locator (worse) to get the ILog in the needed class
3. One configuration can provide you with multiple loggers, which in turn can have multiple appenders that can log to various outputs (db, console, queues etc.) This gives you a lot of flexibility governed by one config file. You can have one config file with two file loggers with different names that will use two different appenders to output data, well, into two files.

The code

```
private  ILog Log  {
    get {
        if (!_ConfiguratorSet) {
            _ConfiguratorSet = true;
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(_ConfigFile)); //<--- STATIC
        }
        return _log;
    }
}
```

is really confusing and wrong. You should only return a log there, so no *ifs* at all. It is a violation of single responsibility principle and possibly the reason of the bug you see.

Comment: How would I go about accomplishing #1--configuring log4net **once**?  This code base has a lot of xml file locations stored as config settings.  When project X needs to log, it pulls down the config file path, and passes it to this helper class, which calls XmlConfigurator.Configure and passes it the actual file (new FileInto(_ConfigFile).  Is there an easy way to fix this without re-engineering a lot of stuff?

Comment: In my projects I used an approach where one VS solution contains a project, that's typically shared by other projects withing the solution. The project is usually called `Core` or `Commons`. This is where I would keep a static class that provides static method to configure log4net and static method to get log by name. Usually one solution has a single point of entry, so I call `Configure` method there. Do you have many points of entry in one VS solution (such as web project, Services, Win apps)?

Comment: In that way project X can pass only the name of the looger it needs, or is it a more complex case?

Comment: I think this was just written poorly.  The whole point of this code is to be able to dynamically change config info—it was just executed poorly.  I think I need to look into log4net and see how to set up the config sections it needs in...a config file, then have whoever wants to log specify which config section they need.